# Project releases for NX Monorepo and Azure DevOps

Tags: angular, versioning, monorepo, nrwl-nx, semantic-release

We migrated 5 Angular projects into a NX Monorepo, for CI/CD we use Azure DevOps.

Before switching to the monorepo we were using semantic releases, but now this approach would not be so great anymore as there would be just *one* release at the time and the projects in the monorepo taken as unity.

The clear downsite of this is that we would lose visibility on each project's version.

This seems to be still a [hot issue](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/3377#issuecomment-678114678) with monorepos:

> - start with a order-service 1.4 and auth-service 1.4
> - commit something that affects only order-service
> - build (with nx affected:build) order-service 1.5
> - commit something that affects only auth-service
> - build (with nx affected:build) auth-service 1.6

To solve this lack of granular information I might think to implement a custom versioning at project level, though I am not extremely fond of it.

Is there any possible alternative to get more detailed version details of the single projects in a monorepo solution?

Comment: It seems that there is still no official way to solve this situation yet. NRWL Team might release something in the future, but at the time of writing nothing is planned yet.

Comment: I've solved this problem by using the nx affected command in combo with build tags. I've added an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76603663/azure-pipeline-conditional-release-with-nx-monorepo/76603664#76603664