# Azure pipeline conditional release with NX monorepo

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, monorepo

We have a NX monorepo with several projects inside and are using nx affected to determine which projects have been touched. This works very nicely for our build pipelines but we want to release our projects only when they are actually changed. We want to have multiple release pipelines for each of our projects that only get triggered when they are actually touched.

Answer (score 2):

After investigation, we came to the conclusion that it is actually possible! The path that we have chosen is to set build tags. Note that these are different from git tags(!).

The first thing we needed to do is to determine which projects are changed and tag the build with those projects. We did this by leveraging bash, nx, and jq to give us a comma separated list. We've added the following task to our build pipeline:

```yaml
      - script: |
          projects=`npx nx show projects --affected --json --base=$(BASE_SHA) --head=$(HEAD_SHA) | jq -r '.|@csv' | tr -d '"'`
          echo "Touched projects:"
          echo $projects

          for project in ${projects//,/ }
          do
            echo "##vso[build.addbuildtag]$project"
            echo "Creating tag for: $project"
          done
        displayName: 'Tag build'
```

This way our build gets tagged and we can define a build tag filter in the release pipeline. This can be done by going to edit pipeline in the release section and under artifacts, click the lighting icon, and under build branch filters you can define your branches + the build tags:

[image: build tag]

By doing this the release branch will only be triggered when a specific tag is there.

Comment: I'm pursuing the same goal under turborepo, and this looks really promising. Thanks for taking the time to self-answer. Really useful stuff.